# Does there exist a submersion $f : S^1*R \to R^2$?

Tags: geometry

I know that does not exist a submersion between $S^1$ and $R$, because $S^1$ is compact and $R$ is not, but I'm not sure about these products.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  Let $(\theta,x)\in S^1\times \mathbb{R}$ be coordinates, with $\theta$ in radians.  Then, thinking of $\mathbb{R}^2$ as $\mathbb{C}$ let $f(\theta,x)=e^{x+i\theta}$.

Since this is $e^x\cos\theta + i e^x\sin\theta$, the Jacobian matrix with respect to the real and imaginary parts is
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
-e^x\sin\theta & e^x\cos\theta \\
e^x\cos\theta & e^x\sin\theta
\end{bmatrix}
$$
whose determinant is $-e^{2x}(\sin^2\theta-\cos^2\theta)=-e^{2x}$, which is always nonzero.